# Definition formal group law in the book complex cobordism.... of Doug Ravenel

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, formal-groups

I have read the chapter from the Complex Cobordism.... book of Doug Ravenel.

It is here https://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/mybooks/ravenelA2.pdf.

In the definitions $(A2.1.19)$, page $341$,  it is mentioned that-

> If $x$ and $y$ are elements in an $R$-algebra $A$ which also "contains the
>   power series $F(x,y)$", let $$x +_F y = F(x,y).$$

This definition seems to be in different language what I know from other sources and $x+_F y=F(x,y)$ is simply giving the group structure.

What does the phrase "contains the power series $F(x,y)$ " mean?

Here $x$ and $y$ are variables from $A$.

I have specifically problem with word $\text{contains}$.

So how does and in what sense  $x$ and $y$  $\text{contains}$ the power series $F(x,y)$  ?

Comment: No idea why this got two downvotes.  It is a very reasonable question.

Comment: I know someone may disagree with me.But I think downvoting is not a good solution unless the question is in very poor oriented or something else but suggesting the OP or editing the question should be a good way.We must confess not all are equally progressed and has equal digitization scope around the world. In my circle, I have seen fear of asking question in math.stackexchange due to poor knowledge in math typing (though it can not be good reason but it is a reason). Also in my circle there are many who asked question and got downvoted and deferred themselves from asking further questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is $A$ which is supposed to contain the power series $F(x,y)$, not $x$ and $y$.  That doesn't really clarify much though--what does it mean for $A$ to contain $F(x,y)$?  Ravenel seems to be using this phrase in an imprecise informal sense, just saying that $A$ is such that it makes sense to evaluate the infinite sum $F(x,y)$ in $A$.  To make this more precise, in practice what he means is that $A$ is complete with respect to some ideal $I$ which contains both $x$ and $y$, so that the power series $F(x,y)$ converges in the $I$-adic topology.  For instance, typically $A$ will be something like a power series ring $B[[t]]$ for some $R$-algebra $B$, and $x$ and $y$ will be elements with no constant term so that any power series in $x$ and $y$ converges in the $t$-adic topology.

Comment: Thank you very much for giving clear idea. It helped me a lot to understand. Nice answer